# Unable to fill in input field using capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

I have javascript feature specs that are working fine with selenium, but I'd like to switch to capybara-webkit for a number of reasons (CI, not popping up a browser window, etc).

I'm trying to switch over from selenium, but something is preventing my code from working correctly. I have the following helper:

```
def capybara_login(user)
  visit login_path
  fill_in "email", with: user.email
  fill_in "password", with: user.password
  click_button "Log in"
end
```

Here's my input field that is being outputted:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="you@domain.com" autocomplete="off">
```

I've tested that user.email is not nil. For some reason when I use capybara-webkit, this fails and nothing is filled in (I'm checking by doing a save_and_open_page). However, this code works fine if I use regular capybara(non js) or selenium for js.

Am I missing something? Any ideas as to what could be preventing capybara webkit from filling in these fields?

EDIT: Thank you Tom for helping out. So save and open page will not show any input in those fields.

I was able to use `save_and_open_screenshot` to see that the page was actually just stuck on the loading image on the login screen. If I do a "sleep(1)" it logs in just fine.

Wondering what strategies people use to deal with this...waiting until the page loads to continue? Whats the reasoning behind not having Capybara do this by default? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Since filling in a field only changes the elements value property (not the value attribute), `#save_and_open_page` is not a valid way to check if a field is changed - it will show its original content.  `puts find(:field, 'email').value` will output the value property of the element if you need to check it (`#save_and_open_screenshot` should show too).  As to why it's not filling in, do you have any JS behavior that is attaching to email fields (validation,  etc) - and may be attaching after its already been filled in? You can check that by putting a `sleep 10` or so before the fill_in call.

Comment: Tom, I don't know who you are, but you keep answering my questions and I really appreciate it, haha! OK, thats a great point and it makes sense as to why I'm not seeing the filled in value. I just removed the entire head section of my page and it logged in fine - so something is conflicting. Maybe turbolinks. Will report back with more info. And there IS JS running on that email field, I think...I'll check that too.

Comment: I am the main developer of Capybara nowadays (took over from jnicklas about two years ago) so I have an interest in making sure people use it "correctly" :) - Capybara has a reputation in some circles of being flaky, but it's usually due to people just not understanding what they're doing and/or not reading the documentation to use the correct methods (way too much use of #all for instance - which has a couple of major gotchas that lead to test instability)

Comment: See my edit above. The page just wasn't loaded all the way yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara has no way of knowing when a page is "fully" loaded, since many pages will load asynchronously, dynamically as needed, etc.  In fact Capybara is showing you an issue with your pages usability since a user could technically interact with elements before they're actually usable - in this case Capybara is probably quicker than any user could be, but still...  Because of this you need to determine what the widgets you're using do on the page and what changes they make -  For instance does a class get set on the body element when a library has finished processing the page, does an input field have a class/attribute added when it's been augmented, etc.  Once you've determined that you can tell Capybara to do something like

```
expect(page).to have_selector('body.class_added_when_ready')
```

to make sure the page is fully interactable

Answer (score 0):

This was totally a fluke with some javascript running on my end. At some point I thought it was a good idea to allow a 300ms delay for ladda loaders to fully animate before submitting a form. This was causing capybara to choke. I was able to isolate this problem to that specific code.

Thanks for your help, Tom!